# Woocommerce: Stop Add to Cart jumping to top when quantity added

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I was having a problem with WooCommerce where the Ajax Add to Cart was only adding 1 despite multiple quantities being selected on Shop Archive Page.

I turned the Ajax off in the settings, and used this solution found on here. I replaced the wp-content/themes/your-theme/templates/loop/add-to-cart.php content with:

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom Loop Add to Cart.
 *
 * Template with quantity and ajax.
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly.

global $product;
?>

<?php if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>

    <a href="<?php echo apply_filters( 'out_of_stock_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>" class="button"><?php echo apply_filters( 'out_of_stock_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></a>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php
        $link = array(
            'url'   => '',
            'label' => '',
            'class' => ''
        );

        switch ( $product->product_type ) {
            case "variable" :
                $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'variable_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'variable_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Select options', 'woocommerce' ) );
            break;
            case "grouped" :
                $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'grouped_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'grouped_add_to_cart_text', __( 'View options', 'woocommerce' ) );
            break;
            case "external" :
                $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'external_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'external_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) );
            break;
            default :
                if ( $product->is_purchasable() ) {
                    $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_url', esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) );
                    $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_text', __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ) );
                    $link['class']  = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_class', 'add_to_cart_button' );
                } else {
                    $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'not_purchasable_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                    $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'not_purchasable_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) );
                }
            break;
        }

        // If there is a simple product.
        if ( $product->product_type == 'simple' ) {
            ?>
            <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <?php
                    // Displays the quantity box.
                    woocommerce_quantity_input();

                    // Display the submit button.
                    echo sprintf( '<button type="submit" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="1" class="%s button product_type_simple">%s</button>', esc_attr( $product->id ), esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ), esc_attr( $link['class'] ), esc_html( $link['label'] ) );
                ?>
            </form>
            <?php
        } else {
          echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', sprintf('<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s button product_type_%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $link['url'] ), esc_attr( $product->id ), esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ), esc_attr( $link['class'] ), esc_attr( $product->product_type ), esc_html( $link['label'] ) ), $product, $link );
        }

    ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

And added this code to functions.php

```
    function cs_wc_loop_add_to_cart_scripts() {
    if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product() ) : ?>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(document).on( 'change', '.quantity .qty', function() {
            $(this).parent('.quantity').next('.add_to_cart_button').attr('data-quantity', $(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>

    <?php endif;
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cs_wc_loop_add_to_cart_scripts' );
```

That fixes the issue with multiples being added, but now the shop returns to the top of the page to display the add to cart message when you add something to the basket. How can I keep it so that the navigation stays in the current location so the customer does not have to scroll down again?

Comment: Visit this topic
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642872/refresh-page-and-keep-scroll-position