# FullCalendar - Submiting form in event click and scroll adjustment after submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar in my code and I want to adjust the scroll position after (and only after) an event is clicked. I can do that by having  $(window).scrollTop($("#MyId").offset().top) in eventclick but my problem is that i need to submit a form on each click as well and that causes a page reload. so i lose my scroll position. i can't do the scroll positioning in eventAfterAllRender or loading either, since i only want it to happen after an eventclick.
Is there anyway I can know that reload is happening after an eventclick? not for example, after choosing a new date on the calendar?
I really tried everything which came to my mind but I didn't get anywhere. any idea would be appreciated :)

Update:
Part of the code I was trying to explain:
the eventClick option of my fullcalendar:

```
 eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

$(window).scrollTop($("#IdOfTheDivIWantToJumpToAfterAnEventIsClicked").offset().top);

// Now I need To submit my form everytime I click on an event which makes the page loses scroll position.


            $("#MyForm").submit();
        },
```

I hope it is clearer now..

Comment: A small image explaining scenario or code would help. We are shooting in the dark here.

Comment: I hope am clearer now.. it is the eventclick option of my fullcalendar. i lose my window scroll bar position due to the form submission i need to do on each event click.

Comment: When you submit the form, the page will be redirected right?

Comment: well.. when i click on an event, another container on the same page gets populated with the right information related to that event ( but yes, url is set in "event" and it sends data to the right action in my controller ).. the page is the same, but each eventclick has a form submit and reloads the same page. so when by each click, page is scrolled to the right div, the scroll position is lost by form submit and page reload.

Comment: Basically you want to retain page scroll even after page reload.. Is that what you want? If that is the case, [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642872/refresh-page-and-keep-scroll-position) a question that might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing:
I added a hidden input field to my form and when an event is clicked, I filled up the input field value with a string (for example "Clicked")

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            $("#MyNewHiddenInputField").val("Clicked");
            $("#MyForm").submit();
        }
```

Then if this input field is filled with a value (which happens only by a click on an event), I  fill the hidden field value through my controller on form submit to save the hidden field value after the page reload.

and after i used this value in fullcalendar loading, i just remove its value..

```
loading: function (isLoading, view) {
            // some code
            if (isLoading) {
                //some code
            } else {

                if ($("#MyNewHiddenInputField").val() == "Clicked" && // some other conditions) {
                    // Do what you wanna do
                }


                // Now clear my hidden field
                $("#Clicked").val("");
            }
        }
```

therefore, page load after an event click will be recognized from other type of loading. i hope am clear!

i am not sure if there is any better way to do it, if i come across a better solution, i will update my answer :)