# Refresh a site page just like pressing F5 or clicking refresh button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, browser, microsoft-edge

I have looked around and don't see anything about what I'm asking, only turning this off...

So I'm using Microsoft Edge and when I run my ASP.Net Core web app, there's changes that I want to show. I can press F5 or click the refresh button and the page doesn't flash or it doesn't look like it reloads except for the data showing up. Or if I scroll down the page, hit the refresh button where the page then does flash, it returns back to the spot that I was scrolled to before hitting refresh button. How can I make this happen in code?

In JavaScript I can force a page refresh with `location.reload()` except this seems to do a complete "hard" refresh and does not resume back to the position I was scrolled down to. So how can F5 do this but I can't? I assume there must be a way.

I've searched and searched but everyone wants to turn this off not on. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use AJAX. With jQuery, all you need to do is `$("#container").get("page.html");`

Comment: @ChrisG Slightly more involved than that. You'd be repeating the `<head>` and everything inside your `#container` over and over again.

Comment: @mpen I assumed it's obvious that page.html only contains content, not the entire document. It was just an example line, not a complete solution.

Comment: Something like that may have some success in it. I will see about working with this. Thanks for the comments everyone.

Comment: I guess the only real thing I'm confused on is what do I do with `$('#container-fluid').get('page.html')` ? I'm alerting this and am getting back undefined. This shows how newbish I am lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to refresh the page:

```
//code to refresh the page
var page_y = $( document ).scrollTop();
window.location.href = window.location.href + '?page_y=' + page_y;
```

And place this code in a `script` tag at the bottom of `body`:

```
//code to handle setting page offset on load
$(function() {
    if ( window.location.href.indexOf( 'page_y' ) != -1 ) {
        //gets the number from end of url
        var match = window.location.href.split('?')[1].match( /\d+$/ );
        var page_y = match[0];

        //sets the page offset 
        $( 'html, body' ).scrollTop( page_y );
    }
});
```

Code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17643341/6152171

Comment: The idea is good, but the solution isn't thought well through. Assume the page is refreshed like this twice - then it looks like this: `https://www.example.com?page_y=364?page_y=532`. As you can see, it doesn't work the second time. It also doesn't work if the URL already contains other GET parameters. And if the URL is `https://www.example.com/no_page_yet`, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Aloso I didn't think of that idea, follow the link to the original post

Comment: I did find a really awesome solution but I cannot post it because somehow I am banned from posting answers when I've never posted an answer before on this site.