# What can cause scroll to top?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

A page in a React always scrolls to the top on `history` navigation. I have trouble figuring out what causes the scroll-to-top.

- There is no `window.scrollTo()` that does this
- There is no `.focus()` event that focuses on an element higher up and moves scroll position
- The big React components do not unmount which would cause the page to be shorter, which would move scroll position

So what else is there that can cause `document.documentElement.scrollTop` to be set to `0`?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any fallback screen involved in the transition, may be a loading/intermediate frame with minimum height.. You can work on something like mentioned [React Router v4 - Keep scrolling position when switching components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906708/react-router-v4-keep-scrolling-position-when-switching-components)

```js
function buttonClick() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.add("reduceHeight");
    setTimeout(()=>document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.remove("reduceHeight"),2000);
  }
```

```css
#myDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#myDiv.reduceHeight {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 90vh;
}
button {
  position: fixed;
  top:100px;
  right:100px;
  z-index:100;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body >
<div id="myDiv">
  Scroll and Click the Simulate Button
  
</div>

<button onClick="buttonClick()">Simulate intermediate!</button>
</body>
</html>
```