# How to keep page position when pressed refresh button/code

Tags: jquery, scroll, position, refresh

How to keep page position when pressed refresh button/code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#content").append('<div class="right"><div class="refreshup"><img src="/images/refresh.png" title="Page refresh" alt="Page refresh" /></div></div>');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $(".refreshup").fadeIn()
        } else {
            $(".refreshup").fadeOut()
        }
    });
    $('.refreshup').click(function() {
        location.reload(true);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

And refresh without clear/empty cache & cookies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh Page and Keep Scroll Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642872/refresh-page-and-keep-scroll-position)

Comment: No, this not help me. Solved with this thread: https://www.redips.net/javascript/maintain-scroll-position/