# Page reload with correct scroll position

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I want to reload a webpage to the same scroll position, using

```
document.location.reload();
```

Works like a charm in all browsers except Edge. Edge refreshes to the top of the page.

Sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body { padding-top: 150%; }
    </style>
    <script> 
    function locationreload() { 
        document.location.reload(); 
        } 
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="locationreload()" >
        Reload
    </button>
</body>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: you could use an anchor or save scrollTop somewhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh Page and Keep Scroll Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642872/refresh-page-and-keep-scroll-position)

Comment: I test the answer from the thread suggested by @axelaxel and find that it is working in Edge too. So it can help to solve the issue for Edge. If you are available to use JQuery than you can also refer this example. Ref: https://codepen.io/patrickkahl/pen/KFmAb

Answer (score 1):

Actually that function doesn't work on edge. You can save the scroll position in the localStorage and set it back when the page loads.

```
function locationreload() { 
    window.localStorage.setItem('position', window.pageYOffset);
    window.pageYOffset = window.localStorage.getItem('position');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well you could save the `scrollTop` of the page in the `localStorage` and scroll to that position on window reload.