# Refresh Django template while maintaining scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a Django template where I call a view by clicking a button. The view function returns a `HttpResponseRedirect` to the same page. **I want the page to return/refresh to the same scroll position as when the user clicked the button.**

Here's what I've tried so far:

**Attempt 1:** Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35750479/5674156) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload), I added an `onsubmit` to the form as follows:

```
<form action="{% url 'buy' market.id %}" method="post" onsubmit="return refreshToSameScroll()">
```

...calling `location.reload()` through the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshToSameScroll() {
        location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

But that didn't work.

**Attempt 2**: I then tried the following combination, reworked from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17646165/5674156):

```
<form action="{% url 'buy' market.id %}" method="post" onsubmit="return saveScroll()">
```

...with this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function saveScroll () {
        var page_y = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop;
        window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?page_y=' + page_y;
      }

      window.onload = function () {
        if ( window.location.href.indexOf('page_y') != -1 ) {
          var match = window.location.href.split('?')[1].split("&")[0].split("=");
          document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop = match[1];
          }
      }
</script>
```

The idea here being that clicking the button saves the scroll position, which then gets picked back up once the page reloads/refreshes. But that didn't work either.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?