# Keep scroll position in an element on page on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, page-refresh

I set a ul of product variants with horizontal scroll. When i scroll and click on a variant, the page refresh and the scroll return to start. I need to maintain the posistion where it was first of refresh to let see the clicked variant.

```css
ul#group_17 {
    width: 150px;
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    list-style: none;
}
li {margin: 0 10px 0 0}
.input-color {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}
span {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="group_17">
  <li class="float-xs-left input-container">
    <label>
      <input class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="17" name="group[17]" value="87">
      <span class="color texture" style="background:black"></span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="float-xs-left input-container">
    <label>
      <input class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="17" name="group[17]" value="88" checked="checked">
      <span class="color texture" style="background:brown;"></span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="float-xs-left input-container">
    <label>
      <input class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="17" name="group[17]" value="89">
      <span class="color texture" style="background:red"></span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="float-xs-left input-container">
    <label>
      <input class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="17" name="group[17]" value="90">
      <span class="color texture" style="background:yellow"></span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can i do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refresh Page and Keep Scroll Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642872/refresh-page-and-keep-scroll-position)

Comment: I don't know how to apply that to my situation